# AJAX doesn't submit the form

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

This does prevent the form from posting. That what `preventDefault` does I understand. However the `update()` function doesn't send the form to the URL provided. I don't understand why?

UPDATE: I have the same script working on other project. I think problem is in my html. I can't figure it out though!

```
<form method="post" id="Name" action="updateContent.cshtml" class="abc hidden">
  <input name="currentInput" type="text" class="navbar-brand logo" value="@content.Name" />
  <input type="submit" name="currentPlaceHolder" value="Name" class="hidden" />
</form>
```

```js
$(function () {
   $('.abc').submit(function (ev) {
     var frm = $(this);
     update(frm);
     ev.preventDefault();
   });
});

function update(frm) {
  $.ajax({
    type: frm.attr('method'),
    url: frm.attr('action'),
    data: frm.serialize(),
    success: function (data) {}
  });
}
```

Comment: Your `form` has no `method`. If you don't provide a `type` value the request will not be sent and the `error` method will immediately be invoked

Comment: Tried that. Doesn't work

Comment: Please give more information than 'it doesn't work'. As you can see from the example in my answer below, it works fine. Check the console for errors, and the network tab of the console to see the actual response that's coming back

Comment: try with `method: 'POST'` instead of `type: from.attr('method')`

Comment: Ok Basically I am doing this to not let my page scroll up on post back. When my form submits, it updates certain cells on my database but it scrolls to the top. If I remove ev.preventDefault(); it posts but then page goes to the updateContent.cshtml. If I keep it, then page remains current but it doesn't update the database.

Comment: method : 'POST' is no go too

Comment: `ev.preventDefault();` on top of the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was HTML, not AJAX.

I just added a submit button and it worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Your `form` has no `method`. If you don't provide a `type` value to the `$.ajax()` call then the request will not be sent and the `error` method will immediately be invoked.

Here's an example of this behaviour: https://jsfiddle.net/csw0tu69/

To fix this, simply give the `form` a `method`:

```
<form method="post" id="Name" action="updateContent.cshtml" class="abc hidden">
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/csw0tu69/1/)

Answer (score 0):

### Try this Script

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="Name" action="updateContent.cshtml" class="abc hidden" method="POST">
  <input name="currentInput" type="text" class="navbar-brand logo" value="@content.Name" />
 <input type="submit" name="currentPlaceHolder" value="Name"  />
</form>

<script>

$(function() {
  $('#Name').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var action = $(this).attr('action');
    var method = $(this).attr('method');

    $.ajax({
        url : action,
        method : method,
        data : $(this).serialize(),
        success : function ( res ) {
            alert(res);
        }

    });
  });
});

</script>
```

Comment: That didn't work either! I do however have to use $('.abc') even if $('#Name') worked.